# Использование данных-членов одного класса в другом классе

Tags: ооп, c++

```
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix(ifstream &data);
    ~Matrix();
    fstream data;
    int column;
    int row;
    double **matrix;
private:
    void initMatrix(double **&matrix, int row, int column);
    int getRow(ifstream &data);
    int getColumn(ifstream &data);
    void fillMatrix(double **&matrix, int row, int column, ifstream &data);
    void deleteMatrix(double **&matrix, int row);
};
```

Как можно использовать double **matrix (просматривать элементы) в объекте другого класса.

Comment: странный у Вас класс. 

    int column;
    int row;
    double **matrix;

должно быть приватным, а вот методы `getRow`, `fillMatrix` похоже что публичными.

Comment: Вам не должно хотеться такого. Данные класса должны быть приватными деталями имплементации, другие классы не имеют права знать о них и уж тем более пользоваться ими. Иначе хаос в вашей программе неизбежен.

Answer (score 1):

объявить класс дружественным.

например:

```
class Matrix
{
public:
    friend class имя_вашего_другого_класса; // позволит залезать в приватную часть для указанного класса
    Matrix(ifstream &data);
    ~Matrix();
    fstream data;
    int column;
    int row;
    double **matrix;
private:
    void initMatrix(double **&matrix, int row, int column);
    int getRow(ifstream &data);
    int getColumn(ifstream &data);
    void fillMatrix(double **&matrix, int row, int column, ifstream &data);
    void deleteMatrix(double **&matrix, int row);
};
```

но это спорный способ его не рекомендуется использовать, лутше напишите отдельный метод для этого.

Comment: а зачем автору вопроса заглядывать в приватную часть класса? оно у него и так все в public'е висит?

Comment: точно, не заметил